# Setting different configuration on dev server and prod server

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, datasource, jndi

I develop a web application. i use tomcat on my desktop to develop and then i deploy a war file on a iseries websphere application server (8.5) 
I've defined a datasource on each server, ProxyDs.

My problem is on tomcat, i must code this :
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ProxyDS");
and on websphere this :
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ProxyDS");

what is the solution to have a code that works on the development server and on the production server ?

I thought of creating a Properties file that would be different on development server and production server, but the properties file would have to be out of the war file. (if it is embedded in the war file, it will be the same on the dev server and prod server, so i'm back to square one)

Maybe there is another solution than the properties file, i'm open to any idea

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028171/3701228). You still should use `java:comp/env/jdbc/ProxyDS` in WebSphere, but this is resource reference and it should be mapped to the JNDI name of the datasource in the server. That reference can be mapped to different JNDI in development server and in production. You can do it either via admin console, wsadmin installation script, or providing `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file.